# remove last 100 elements from query result in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a query like this

```
db.Usage.find({'Usage': "",'Rating': "", 'Average Ratings': ""}).count()
1500
```

I want to remove last 500 entries of this query. Is their a way to remove the last 500 entries or I have to remove all the documents matching this query at once and then insert the valid 1000 documents again

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to remove all the documents matching this query at once and then insert the valid 1000 documents again

Answer (score 1):

```
it = db.Usage.find({'Usage': "",'Rating': "", 'Average Ratings': ""})[1001:1500]

to_rem = []
for doc in iter:
    to_rem.append( doc['_id'] )


try:
    db.Usage.remove( {'_id' :{ '$in': to_rem } })
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```